# How does partition in sybase works?

Tags: sybase

I am trying to Create a partitioned table in Sybase IQ

```
create table demo(id varchar(20),name varchar(20),city varchar(20))
partition by city
```

It throws error

```
 Error: Syntax error near 'city' on line 2 (State:37000, Native Code: FFFFFF7D)
```

How to overwrite a particular partition in Sybase while inserting the records for that existing partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. 
Syntax is:

```
... 
partition by range (<column>) 
(<partition-name-1> values <= (<ptn-max-value>), ...more partitions...)
```